# Автоинкремент версии/билда проекта Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, build, autoincrement

Best practice автоинкремента версии/билда относительно C# / Visual Studio?

Какой путь лучше использовать при одной ветке апликухи, а как нужно действовать когда веток несколько? ( И почему, если это не очевидно по ответу :)

Есть ли какие подводные камни, на которые нужно обратить внимание при использовании автоинкремента? Как в целом, так и в часности относительно пути который советуете.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Самые подводные грабли тут - место хранения счетчика билдов. В то время когда весь мир пользуется распределенными системами хранения исходников - номер билда все еще должен проставляться в одном месте.

Скорее всего, лучше забить на простановку версий в локальных сборках и проставлять версию только на билд-сервере.

Во время сборки можно генерировать файл, к примеру, `CommonAssemblyInfo.cs`, который подключен ко всем проектам как ссылка:

```
<Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
<Compile Include="..\CommonAssemblyInfo.cs">
  <Link>Properties\CommonAssemblyInfo.cs</Link>
</Compile>
```

При генерации файла на этапе сборки отталкиваться можно вот от такого шаблона:

```
using System.Reflection;

// General Information about an assembly is controlled through the following 
// set of attributes. Change these attribute values to modify the information
// associated with an assembly.
[assembly: AssemblyCompany("...")]
[assembly: AssemblyProduct("...")]
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("...")]
[assembly: AssemblyTrademark("...")]
[assembly: AssemblyCulture("ru-RU")]

[assembly: AssemblyVersion("$(VersionFull)")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("$(VersionFull)")]
[assembly: AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute("$(ProductVersion)")]
[assembly: AssemblyMetadata("Git:Branch", "$(GitBranch)")]
[assembly: AssemblyMetadata("Git:CommitHash", "$(GitCommitHash)")]
```

Старшие числа номера версии (Major, Minor, Build/Hotfix) имеет смысл задавать вручную, меняя при выпуске очередного релиза. При работе в подходе Agile в качестве третьей цифры напрашивается номер спринта.

Младшую цифру (Revision) лучше брать из переменных билд-сервера, чтобы она соответствовала номеру билда.

Текущую ветку гита можно прочитать из .git/HEAD
Текущий коммит - из .git/refs/heads/{ветка}

Comment: А как насчет пути описанного здесь: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356543/can-i-automatically-increment-the-file-build-version-when-using-visual-studio ? Чем это решение лучше? Более гибкое?

Comment: @Andrew запись текущей даты-времени в последние две части версии - это не автоинкремент

Comment: хм, так там дата/время записывается, не заметил. Спасибо)

Comment: А если проэкт маленький и билд-сервер не используется вовсе? Каков путь лучше ?

Comment: @Andrew если без билд-сервера, то либо дату-время оставить, либо вообще фиксированную. Других вариантов-то и нет, счетчик для автоинкремента попросту негде хранить.

Comment: @Andrew а вот информацию о ветке и коммите в метаданные - можно и для такого проекта добавить.